# More efficient way to merge arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$dateRange = array('2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', ...);
$data = array('2010-01-01' => 5, '2010-01-03' => 7);

foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    $values[$date] = $data[$date];
}
```

`$values` results in:

```
array (
    '2010-01-01' => 5
    '2010-01-02' => null
    '2010-01-03' => 7
    ...
)
```

Seems fairly efficient, but I wonder if there's a simple PHP function that'll handle this.

Comment: http://php.net is your friend... ;)

Comment: so is stackoverflow :) i searched php.net but didn't find a specific function that handles it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$values = array_merge(array_fill_keys($dateRange, null), $data);
```

Whether that's really any more *efficient* can only be found out through testing, but I'd say it's more concise, easy to understand, and *it doesn't throw errors* for non-existent keys in `$data`. :)

Comment: You should switch the order of your arguments, see the docs: "If an array key exists in both arrays, then the element from the first array will be used and the matching key's element from the second array will be ignored." However, array_merge will renumber your keys as soon as it "considers" them numeric. So I would recommend using the + operator instead of array_merge, because it is a lot more predictable. This also preserves values from the first operand when the key exists in the second. Use: $data + array_fill_keys($dateRange, null) or: array_merge($data, array_fill_keys($dateRange, null)

Comment: @ontrack I don't know which docs you're reading, but `array_merge` says: `If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.` I'm using `array_merge` daily, and this is how it works. Also, these are clearly string keys, not numeric keys.

Comment: My quote came from Example #3, I seem to have missed the top of the doc. But that quote is actually specifically about the + operator The reason why (I prefer) the operator is because the behaviour changes as soon as you start to use numeric keys. Ergo: It currently works as expected but stops working in a seemingly similar situation. Something I try to avoid specifically because it advocates bugs. Maybe you want to start using something similar with day-numbers.

Comment: @ontrack There's also something to be said about `array_merge` keeping the sort order intact though. :) You have a point about changing the keys to day numbers, but at that point it'd submit you're talking about a completely different script and would need to reevaluate every operation you're doing on the array anyway. There's no need to go out of your way to make sure your script is internally future-proof. ;) So, just for the record: `$values = $data + array_fill_keys($dateRange, null)` should work the same, except for the order of the result.

Answer (score 1):

There's [`array_merge`](http://us.php.net/array_merge) but it will produce `1 => 2010-01-02` instead of `2010-01-02 => null`.

There are also a whole host of array functions at http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

[**Edit**]: Leaving this answer because of the links, but the other answer accomplishes exactly what you wanted.